# Property with return value in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, swift, kotlin

This is a pretty basic question, but I haven't been able to find any answer on SO yet.

I'm just curious, is there a corresponding way in Java or Kotlin to write a property with a return value, such as there is in Swift:

```swift
class SomeClass {
    let someProperty: SomeType = {
        // create a default value for someProperty inside this closure
        // someValue must be of the same type as SomeType
        return someValue
    }()
}
```

Documentation link: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID232

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [kotlin-constructors](https://www.deadcoderising.com/kotlin-how-to-use-default-parameters-in-functions-and-constructors/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Swift, but if I understand correctly that the closure/lambda is invoked immediately to set an initial value to the property, then this is as simple as:

```kotlin
var someProperty = someValue
```

And if `someValue` is a result of a more complicated logic that can't be represented as a simple expression, then:

```kotlin
var someProperty: SomeType = run {
    ...
    someValue
}
```

As a fact, the provided Swift code is almost a valid Kotlin code as well. We don't have to use `run()`, we can create a lambda and invoke it immediately, as in Swift:

```kotlin
var someProperty: SomeType = {
    ...
    someValue
}()
```

However, this is not considered "the Kotlin way" and IntelliJ IDE even suggest to replace it with `run()`.

Comment: Can I edit this?

Comment: You mean `someProperty`? Yes.

Comment: The edit would kind of be correct, but it's still not quite there as it doesn't initialise the property. I guess there isn't a direct conversion from Swift to Kotlin all the time.

Comment: I should say I might as well have marked this one as the correct answer too...

Comment: @Linus it does in fact initialize the property. I'm not sure what exactly would be different from Swift now. Feel free to mark this one correct

Comment: @IvoBeckers, ok, however it doesn't contain an empty constructor () though? As I've understood it "... = run { return@run ... } is not quite the same thing, right? Although I can find any good documentation right now...

Comment: @Linus ahh, sorry, I missed the fact that you provided the edit ;-) Assuming `someValue` is of type `SomeType` we don't really need to type the property if we don't want to. My original answer was correct. Of course we often prefer to provide the type explicitly for code clarity.

Comment: @Linus adding `return@run` is unnecessary because it automatically returns the last expression in a lambda

Comment: @Linus i don't understand what you mean with empty contructor here.

Comment: @Linus This code runs the code inside `run { }`, it performs some kind of calculations to acquire `someValue` and then sets `someProperty` to `someValue` as its initial value. Then you can change `someProperty` to some other value. I guess this is what the provided Swift code does. Both `: SomeType` and `return@run` are not required - the code does the same thing with or without them.

Answer (score 2):

I think a custom getter is maybe what you are looking for?

```
val someProperty: SomeType
    get() {
        // create a default value for someProperty inside this closure
        // someValue must be of the same type as SomeType
        return someValue
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was already aware of this approach, but will nonetheless mark it correct. I was more looking for a way to not have to use a get() call, since Swift don't use get {...} in their example.

Comment: @Linus First of all I believe this answer does a totally different thing than the Swift code you provided. Documentation you provided says that this Swift code only initializes the property with an initial value. Providing a getter (above Kotlin code) is a totally different thing.

Comment: It's not "totally" different as in using a return function, but it is not quite there either.

Answer (score 0):

What example you are providing of swift is actually similar to custom getter in kotlin.
You can also use custom getter in kotlin for achieving the same result.

```
val someProperty: SomeType
    get() {
        //preform some operations
        return sometype
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).